# Is there a way to create an OpenAPI / Swagger spec for my Salesforce Account?

Tags: rest-api, api, custom-field, rest

I've been using the Saleforce REST API for a while and I'm interested in using an OpenAPI / Swagger spec to auto-generate a SDK using [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) and [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen).

Is there a way to get an OpenAPI / Swagger specification for my Salesforce account? Ideally, I'd like to get one with all my custom fields defined in the definitions / schemas but even one without custom fields would be useful to start.

Comment: Requested on success.salesforce.com.  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cQsxQAE.  Needs 250 upvotes in order to be considered lol.

Comment: Now there are 550 points but only 55 votes. Quite a ways to go.